# How to convert dataframe from list with different number of rows in R?

Tags: r, text-mining

I'm reading text data from many pdf files. I have object that is a list

list description

[image]
As you can see, the elements differ in number of rows. I need to convert that into dataframe for text mining, but when I use function as.data.frame() it gives me an error:

```
as.data.frame(text_from_all_pdf)
```

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 353, 457, 101, 517, 74, 102, 57, 5, 93

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unlisting `text_from_all_pdf` and create a dataframe with one column.

```
data <- data.frame(text = unlist(text_from_all_pdf))
```

Comment: Thank you, thah worked. I want to ask you here to not create a new question. I created the stop words list by using my_stop_words <- head(stopwords::stopwords("pl", source = "stopwords-iso"), 356)    but when I try to make preprocessing with this data_clean <- data %>% 
  mutate(text = text %>% 
           str_to_lower() %>% 
           tm::removeWords(words = my_stop_words$V1) %>%
           str_squish())     it gives me Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `text`.
x $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
i Input `text` is ``%>%`(...)`.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Feel free to ask a separate question for a new issue.